# display entryset of hashmap according to value

Tags: java, swing, loops, hashmap

I have this method here that gets an object from a JList. The object would then be a string  that matches certain values in a hashmap. There are multiple values, for example.

```
 Course1 - John
 Course2 - John
 Course3 - Mary
 Course4 - Mary
```

are there any ways to loop through a hashmap and look for certain value, then place both key & value into a string that can then be added to a list model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for values only, use the keySet() method of the hashmap to get the keys and then loop through them to get the corresponding values.

```
for(String key : hashMap.keySet())
   {
     String value = hashMap.get(key);

     if(searchString.equals(value))
       {
          String keyAndValue = key + value; // this is what you want
       }    
   }
```

If you are searching for both keys and values, use the entrySet() method of the hashmap to get the entries and then loop through them to look for the match.

```
 for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashMap.entrySet())
   {
     String key = entry.getKey();
     String value = entry.getValue();

     if(searchString.equals(key) || searchString.equals(value))
       {
          String keyAndValue = key + value; // this is what you want
       }    
   }
```

Comment: He wants to search by ***value***. You've just reimplemented `get()` as a linear (O(n)) search.

Comment: Ok, I will make changes. I assumed he wanted to search based on both key and value.

Comment: Actually, CodeBlue provided a perfectly working code. You are a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Use a search method which iterates over the map and returns a list of matches:

```
public static ArrayList < String > searchMap ( HashMap map, String value )
{
    ArrayList < String > matchesFound = new ArrayList < String >();
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while ( it.hasNext() )
    {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        if ( entry.getValue() == value )
            matchesFound.add( entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue() );
    }
    return matchesFound;
}
```

Sample usage with populated hashmap data:

```
public static void main ( String [] args )
{
    HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String >();
    map.put( "Course1", "John" );
    map.put( "Course2", "John" );
    map.put( "Course3", "Mary" );
    map.put( "Course4", "Mary" );
    System.out.println( searchMap( map, "Mary" ) );
}
```

Comment: He wants to search by ***value***. You've just reimplemented `get()` as a linear (O(n)) search, although your solution could be easily fixed.

Comment: @JimGarrison review my post please.

Comment: I need to display all matching key/value entries for the input value. So the code provided by codeblue works perfectly. However, I will keep your method in mind in case anything as such may come up in the future.

Comment: @cataschok copy paste and run my code, my post provides you a list of mathces which can easily be used later. the other post re-assigns a variable in each iteration. didn't you get the point?

Comment: @cataschok and also you should accept one answer to award the posts and efforts, at least upvote.

Comment: @cataschok i'm spending my time for a better code for you and you are not upvoting, not fair.